# Error: Variable Not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

In the main file for testing I started with code similar to this.

```
 //Initialize the data type for the vectors and input variables
 if ( choice == 1 ) 
 {
     vector<int>MyVector{};
     vector<int>NewVect{};
     int k1{}, k2{};
 }

 else if ( choice == 2 )
 {
     vector<float>MyVector{};
     vector<float>NewVect{};
     float k1{}, k2{};
 } 
 //Exact Same block for double
 while ( true )
 {
     cout<<": ";
     cin>>k1>>k2;
     if ((k1 == 0 ) && (k2 == 0)) break;
     else
     {
          MyVector.push_back(k1);
          MyVector.push_back(k2);
          continue;
     }
  }
 //Insert Sort Algorithm test, Imported from class InsertSort.
 //NewVector = sort.sort(MyVector)
return 0;    
}
```

It continues like this into two other else if statements declaring float and double respectively ( using the same variable names ). The compilation however stops and says that k1, k2, MyVector, and NewVector were not declared in this scope further into the program. I declared it within the "global" portion of main so I'm not really understanding why the declaration isn't happening. Is it not possible to try to declare the same variable of a different type within if/else if statements?

I'm trying to do it this way to avoid additional tests within the input loop, that way there is one check for the data type, the proper data types are defined and the code will be shorter than it would have been. Any ideas what's happening?

EDIT: Code Added.

Comment: This may be due to a previous parse error. Did you check carefully? Comment part of the code.

Comment: The variables exist only within the scope of the `if` statement because that is where you declared them.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because details matter here. Wild guess: variables in C++ are "visible" only in the closest scope, i.e. in your snippet none of variables will be visible outside of the corresponding `if` branch.

Comment: would you like to provide a more complete code so we can know how do you declared them in the "global portion of the main" and how do you use them further into the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare a variable which's type depends on a run-time condition. Types of variables are declared/specified at compile time. Knowing that, you tried to declare different types inside the if blocs, but then, the scope of each variable is limited to the bloc in which it is declared.

What you are trying can be achieved using some kind of *polymorphic variable*, or variable of *any* type, which will be available in `C++17` but not before, under the name of `std::any`. In the mean time, you can try to make for yourself something similar using `unions`. The following can provide a starting example to making your own `any` type, the example defines an `any` that holds either an `int` or a `double`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct any {
  union { int intVal = 0; double dblVal;};
  enum {Int = 1, Dbl = 2} type = Int;

  any(int val) : intVal(val) {type = Int;}
  any(double val) : dblVal(val) {type = Dbl;}
  any() {}
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const any& x) {
    switch(x.type) {
        case any::Int : os << x.intVal; break;
        case any::Dbl : os << x.dblVal; break;
    }
    return os;
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<any> vect;
    any k1, k2;

    vect.emplace_back(3);
    vect.emplace_back(4);
    vect.emplace_back(9.5);
    vect.emplace_back(10.5);

    for (const auto& i: vect)
        std::cout << i << "  ";
}
```

Comment: You understood what I am trying to do. Your code is a little over my head however. I understand that there is a "class" being used to but union is unfamiliar to me and the syntax for operator overloading is still very alien and mysterious. I'll run it through and see if I can get it to work in this context and better understand it.

Comment: @SuperUser_Novice I understand that. Basically, the union is a field that can hold one of the types you want your variable to hold, and the `type` enumerated field holds the runtime "type" of the variable according to what you assign to it. This is what you wanted to do with your `choice` variable.

Comment: as for the `<<` overload, dont worry for it, you can do yourself the test on the `type` when outputting a variable of type `any`. The overload is usually made to encapsulate this code in one place.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variables are only defined inside an `if` statement.
If you want to use those variables after the end of the `if` statement, you need to declare them before the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

try to put k1 and k2 out of if condition

```
int k1{}, k2{};
if ( choice == 1 ) 
{
 vector<int>Myvector{};
 vector<int>NewVect{};
}
```

always try to declare variable before if statement